# ModuleNotFound Error when import a package from another package that imports another package

Tags: python, tkinter, module

[folder structure click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppDcq.png)

My folder structure looks like this.

In app.py, I have:

```
from components import ControlFrame
```

In ControlFrame.py, I have:

```
import MainFrame, OutputFrame, ButtonFrame, ControlFrame
```

However, when I run ControlFrame.py it's good but when I run app.py I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/ehacimc/OneDrive - Ericsson/Desktop/KPI_GENERATOR/KPI_PPT_GENERATOR_CODE/src/app.py", line 19, in <module>
    from components import ControlFrame
  File "c:\Users\ehacimc\OneDrive - Ericsson\Desktop\KPI_GENERATOR\KPI_PPT_GENERATOR_CODE\src\components\ControlFrame.py", line 3, in <module>
    import MainFrame, OutputFrame, ButtonFrame, ControlFrame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MainFrame'
```

Comment: I think what you want in `app.py` is `from components.ControlFrame import ControlFrame` - in Python you import from modules (Python files) not from folders. You may also run into some issues with your filenames matching your class names, but Python is usually smart enough to avoid this (still bad practice howerever). See here for more info about [relative imports](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/#relative-imports)

Comment: If those files are used as sub-modules, then use `from . import MainFrame, OutputFrame, ButtonFrame` instead inside `ControlFrame.py`.  Why do you import itself inside `ControlFrame.py`?